# Swift Cordova bridge undefined error

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I'm following instructions at http://moduscreate.com/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-for-ios/ to generate a Swift based Cordova plugin for IOS.

When I get as far as adding the IOS platform via command 'cordova platform add ios' I'm expecting something like the example:

```
Adding ios project...

iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.0.1

Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project

Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm

Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios

Installing "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" for ios

Update IOS build setting SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER to: 

/Users/simon/projects/modus/swiftplugin/modusechopluginswift/testapp2/platforms/ios/TestApp/Bridging-Header.h

Update IOS build setting EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT to: YES
```

What I actually get is:

```
Adding ios project...

Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:

Path: platforms/ios

Package: com.moduscreate.testapp

Name: TestApp

iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.2.1

Installing "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" for ios

Error: undefined is not a function
```

The platforms folder has a generated IOS subfolder with content.

I assume the problem is with the cordova-plugin-add-swift-support plugin.

I'm running xCode 8.0 on macOS Sierra 10.12.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the tutorial you were following.  I recently updated it to address changes for Swift 3, so if you want to try this with the latest Cordova, XCode 8.2 and Swift 3 syntax, I've produced a new tutorial [here](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios-e314acf68a47#.1xxihldrj).  Following this may solve your issues.